# Java GWT dependency injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, gwt, gwt-platform

We now have in our project a class which has 1000 lines of `bindPresenter(...)` in its only method that starts when app starts. I'm worried about performance: can such injection slow down application? Am i right that it is not lazy injection and all presentors are creating with all their dependencies at the start of application?

We used profiler and it seems like injection really slow down start, but we are not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that your 1000 of `bind` statements slow down your application's load time. From [GWTP's  `Presenter` docs](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/blob/master/gwtp-core/gwtp-mvp-client/src/main/java/com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/Presenter.java):

> Each presenter is associated to a Proxy which is responsible for listening to the
>     various events of interest for this presenter. This makes it possible to lazily instantiate
>     the presenter and use GWT code splitting.

Since `Presenter`s are lazy-instantiated, your slow start might be caused by somthing else.

One thing that might slow down your load time is if you do heavy `PresenterWidget` injection, without using Gin's `Provider`s:

```
@Inject
ParentPresenter(
  SomePresenterWidget a, 
  SomePresenterWidget b) {
  // ...
}
```

Injecting many `PresenterWidget`s like this requires to build the `PresenterWidget`s up front, which might cause loading slowdowns. You could use `Provider`s to lazy-load `PresenterWidget`s:

```
@Inject
ParentPresenter(
  Provider<SomePresenterWidget> a, 
  Provider<SomePresenterWidget> b) {
  // ...
}
```

and only instantiate the `PresenterWidget`s using `provider.get()` when needed.